# Magento local.xml not regonising 2 js files

Tags: javascript, xml, magento

I am using magento local.xml to add js files - however when i use 2 together one or the other works not both together; has any one got any idea how i can make these work together?

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

If i remove one (either) they do work on their own.

thanks

Comment: Never mind hadn't see the last part your question

Comment: I think you are including jQuery twice, check the source, it could even be a module causing this. Does everything work when you remove jQuery?

Comment: Please add jquery first, and if you know how to debug/inspect in browser, please look at network inspect and see if the files are found or not, and CHECK CONSOLE if files are clashing, dependencies issues.

Comment: it looks that your js is conflicting with existing js.please check console or you can check by ctrl+u.whether jquery is included multiple time or not